# Enum is not a class or namespace name

Tags: c++11

I have the following enum:

```
struct CTEnums
{
    enum class HashType : int
    {
        SHA1 = 0,
        SHA256 = 1,
        SHA384 = 2,
        SHA512 = 3,
        MD5 = 4
    };

    enum class KeySize : int
    {
        KeySize1 = 0,
        KeySize224 = 1,
        KeySize256 = 2,
        KeySize384 = 3,
        KeySize512 = 4
    };
};
```

I have a class called Encryption that with a function:

```
 void SetHash(CTEnums::HashType hash_type);
```

I keep getting error:

> C2653: CTEnums is not a class or namespace name
>   C2061: syntax error: identifer HashType

I have also tried the following version of the enum:

```
struct CTEnums
{
    enum HashType
    {
        SHA1 = 0,
        SHA256 = 1,
        SHA384 = 2,
        SHA512 = 3,
        MD5 = 4
    };

    enum KeySize
    {
        KeySize1 = 0,
        KeySize224 = 1,
        KeySize256 = 2,
        KeySize384 = 3,
        KeySize512 = 4
    };
};
```

But I get the same error.  Im using Qt with VS2013 and its driving me crazy

**Update**

Ok I renamed my files from enums.h to ctcodes.h and modified the code as follow:

```
enum class HashType : int
{
    SHA1 = 0,
    SHA256 = 1,
    SHA384 = 2,
    SHA512 = 3,
    MD5 = 4
};

enum class KeySize : int
{
    KeySize1 = 0,
    KeySize224 = 1,
    KeySize256 = 2,
    KeySize384 = 3,
    KeySize512 = 4
};

enum class OSType : int
{
    Windows = 0,
    OSx = 1,
    Linux = 2
};
```

And now it works.  Makes me wonder if there was a conflict with my header file name.  It was called enums.h

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Could you please provide a [complete self-contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the error?

Comment: GCC is able to compile this correctly on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a242a07963565b9).

Comment: Makes me wonder what Microsoft sells as "C++"... scnr

Comment: But on a more productive note: The error message indicates that the name `CTEnums` was already taken.

Comment: I was reading that there is a problem with Visual Studio.  What I also think the problem was I had a duplicate file.  That is why when I changed the file name everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, the anme `CTEnums` was already taken.

Try your first version with the original file name and change `CTEnums` to something else.